# Tomcat 401 exception even though valid credentials are passed

Tags: authentication, tomcat8, http-status-code-401

We have tomcat 8 hosted on a VM on which we have deployed a couple of services which requires authentication to be passed in the header (LDAP authentication enabled). Sometimes we do observe 401 exceptions from the service. Initially we thought it was the LDAP authentication going for a toss. But on checking the tomcat localhost access log, we see that the username (which generally appears if we pass a user name in the header is not listed) even though basic authentication headers are passed. This happens intermittently. How to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was present in catalina.out all along. The LDAP server was unreachale intermittently and hence were facing the issue.